# wso2ei-6.0.0 can not start in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, wso2, enterprise, integrator

I can not start wso2ei-6.0.0 in eclipse.

The version I am using is developer-studio-ei-eclipse-jee-mars-2-win64-x86_64-1.0.0 version, jdk is 1.8.0.

When I configure the server I select WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.0.0  others select defaults, I encounter an error when trying to start it.

```
OSGi console has been enabled with options: -console
osgi> [2017-03-04 10:33:35,314] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2017-03-04 10:33:35,318] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Windows 7 6.1, amd64
[2017-03-04 10:33:35,319] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre
[2017-03-04 10:33:35,319] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 1.8.0_112
[2017-03-04 10:33:35,319] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.112-b15,Oracle Corporation
[2017-03-04 10:33:35,319] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : D:/wso2/wso2ei-6.0.0
[2017-03-04 10:33:35,319] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : D:/wso2/wso2ei-6.0.0/tmp
[2017-03-04 10:33:35,320] [EI-Core]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : zhu, zh-CN, Asia/Shanghai
[2017-03-04 10:33:35,528] [EI-Core]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter Carbon is configured to use the default keystore (wso2carbon.jks). To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
[2017-03-04 10:33:35,580] [EI-Core]  INFO - GoogleTokenGenDSComponent Activating GoogleTokengen DS component
[2017-03-04 10:33:35,855] [EI-Core]  INFO - KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service
[2017-03-04 10:33:36,037] [EI-Core]  INFO - ManagementModeConfigurationLoader CEP started in Single node mode
[2017-03-04 10:33:45,956] [EI-Core]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Configured Registry in 256ms
[2017-03-04 10:33:46,062] [EI-Core]  INFO - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2017-03-04 10:33:58,313] [EI-Core]  INFO - SolrClient Default Embedded Solr Server Initialized
[2017-03-04 10:33:58,700] [EI-Core]  INFO - UserStoreMgtDSComponent Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2017-03-04 10:34:44,397] [EI-Core]  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
[2017-03-04 10:35:46,336] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
[2017-03-04 10:35:46,341] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required Module: rampart-core-1.6.1-wso2v24
[2017-03-04 10:36:46,335] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
[2017-03-04 10:36:46,336] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required Module: rampart-core-1.6.1-wso2v24
[2017-03-04 10:37:46,334] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
[2017-03-04 10:37:46,335] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required Module: rampart-core-1.6.1-wso2v24
[2017-03-04 10:38:46,334] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
[2017-03-04 10:38:46,334] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required Module: rampart-core-1.6.1-wso2v24
[2017-03-04 10:39:46,335] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
[2017-03-04 10:39:46,335] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required Module: rampart-core-1.6.1-wso2v24
[2017-03-04 10:40:46,334] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
[2017-03-04 10:40:46,334] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required Module: rampart-core-1.6.1-wso2v24
[2017-03-04 10:41:46,335] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
[2017-03-04 10:41:46,335] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required Module: rampart-core-1.6.1-wso2v24
[2017-03-04 10:42:46,334] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:
[2017-03-04 10:42:46,334] [EI-Core]  WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required Module: rampart-core-1.6.1-wso2v24
Carbon Server WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.0.0 at localhost is shutting down...
Carbon Server WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.0.0 at localhost has shut down...
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried the same and could not reproduce the issue after installing updates. However i could guess for a situation where this could happen. Hence I'm suggesting to do the following.

1. Take a new wso2ei-6.0 pack and unziped, lets say the unzip location EI_HOME
2. Start the eclipse, and when starting use a new workspace (i.e do not use the workspace you used earlier)
3. Add a new server in eclipse, when adding a new server, goto "Configure runtime environments" and remove the old ei-server configuration if you already have such.
4. Add new ei server, using the EI_HOME
5. Start the server from eclipse

If you are in a position that you could not use a new ei-6.0 pack, you may do the following.

Goto EI_HOME/wso2/lib folder and list out the files and directories, it should have following files and directories. (i.e in a fresh pack)

```
ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
cipher-text.properties
commons-lang-2.6.0.wso2v1.jar
endorsed/
esapi-2.0.1.jar
org.wso2.carbon.logging-4.4.14.jar
org.wso2.carbon.server-4.4.14.jar
org.wso2.ciphertool-1.0.0-wso2v3.jar
runtimes/
sandesha2-core-1.6.1-wso2v1.jar
tomcat/
transactions.properties
xercesImpl-2.8.1.wso2v2.jar
```

If you have any files,jars other than in above list you may remove those.
Then follow the steps 2-5.

There could be a situation if you have started a EI server before applying updates, it might copy some additional jars to the EI_HOME/wso2/lib location. Which causes this problem (the update resolves this issue), hence the above solution is to fix that by manual removing the copied jars.

Comment: I had the same problem with EI 6.1 and was able to solve with this answer

Comment: I think you are from wso2 development team.So recently  released 6.4 version but this issue is posted 2 years before. You should resolve this issue in this version.

Comment: Now my question is what is meaning of put all jars there?Can you explain it?

Answer (score 1):

thank you very much. I did a java upgrade from 1.8.0_102 to 1.8.0.121 and it works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

I re-downloaded eclipse and the latest version of java. I think it says that you don't have the correct java version installed. It worked fine after I re-downloaded them.